# MatLab Sortrows if statement is true

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I want to sort a table by a simple condition. 
If 3 of 5 vectors in a group are >0 than put that row on top of the table.

I tried it with sortrow but i cant implement this condition.

The concrete case i want to solve is a table which consists of 11 columns. First column shows names assocciated to the values in the rows respectively.  Rest of the columns is splitted into 2 groups for example A1:A5 and B1:B5. If in group A 3 of 5 cells are >0 than put this row on top of the table. First row should logically be the row were every value is >0.

I tried many things including combination of sortrows and if statements but it didnt work.

Maybe you have an idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please add your code, and point to where you think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure that the rows are on top where most values in columns 2-6 are positive.

Here's a solution using `sort`:

```
tbl = ... %# your table
numPositive = sum(tbl(:,2:6)>0,2);

[~,sortIdx] = sort(numPositive,'descend');

sortedTable = tbl(sortIdx,:);
```